# Count days between 2 dates input from keyboard

Tags: c, date, numbers, days

I am a beginner and i'm trying to calculate how many days there are between 2 dates, but i don't understand clearly about time.h, can someone point out my mistakes? Because sec = 0 after being printed. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

main(){



    double sec;

    struct tm BD;
        BD.tm_mday;        
        BD.tm_mon;         
        BD.tm_year;

    struct tm KT;
        KT.tm_mday;        
        KT.tm_mon;         
        KT.tm_year;

    printf("Start date: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&BD.tm_mday,&BD.tm_mon,&BD.tm_year);

    printf("End date: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&KT.tm_mday,&KT.tm_mon,&KT.tm_year);

    sec = difftime(mktime(&KT),mktime(&BD));

    printf("%f",sec); 

// date= sec/86400 //

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  The question is tagged as C++ but this is straight C code.  If you are being taught this as C++ then I would suggest you look elsewhere for C++ teaching.

Comment: If you have access to a C++11 and above compiler, look at the std::chrono namespace http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry i didn't notice it and already edited to C. Can you show me my mistakes? My date's input seems to be bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code fails to set needed fields before calling `mktime()`.  Result: undefined behavior.

```
struct tm BD;

// these 3 lines of code do nothing
BD.tm_mday;        
BD.tm_mon;         
BD.tm_year;

scanf("%d %d %d",&BD.tm_mday,&BD.tm_mon,&BD.tm_year);
// Only 3 of the 9+ fields of `BD` have a defined value.
```

Instead zero the structures first and set `tm_isdst`.  To use `mktime()` properly all fields need to be set first except `tm_yday` and `tm_wday`.  Those 2 fields are ignored for reading.  All fields are updated to their primary range.

As `struct tm` may have more than the defined set of 9 fields, it is easy to initialize the entire structure's fields to zero first to insure *all* fields are set.  Coders often forget to set `tm_isdst` and other optional fields leading to inconsistent results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  struct tm BD = { 0 };
  // Set to -1 to direct mktime() to decide if DST applies or not.
  // or set to 0, or 1, if a specific DST flag is desired.
  BD.tm_isdst = -1; 
  struct tm KT = { 0 };
  KT.tm_isdst = -1; 

  printf("Start date: ");
  if (3 != scanf("%d %d %d", &BD.tm_mday, &BD.tm_mon, &BD.tm_year)) return -1;

  printf("End date: ");
  if (3 != scanf("%d %d %d", &KT.tm_mday, &KT.tm_mon, &KT.tm_year)) return -1;

  double sec = difftime(mktime(&KT), mktime(&BD));

  printf("%f\n", sec);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this example. You need to set the clock to midnight and round the result to an integer, then the calculation is correct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main () {
    struct tm start_date;
    struct tm end_date;
    time_t start_time, end_time;
    double seconds;
    printf("Start date: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&start_date.tm_mday ,&start_date.tm_mon,&start_date.tm_year);
    printf("End date: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&end_date.tm_mday,&end_date.tm_mon,&end_date.tm_year);
    start_date.tm_hour = 0;  start_date.tm_min = 0;  start_date.tm_sec = 0;
    end_date.tm_hour = 0;  end_date.tm_min = 0;  end_date.tm_sec = 0;
    start_time = mktime(&start_date);
    end_time = mktime(&end_date);
    seconds = difftime(end_time, start_time);
    printf ("%d days difference\n", (int) (0.5 + seconds/(60*60*24)));
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
Start date: 23 11 2017
End date: 27 11 2017
4 days difference
```